# Could not load NIB in bundle ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, ios10

On ios10 beta , my app is facing with crashes with exception: 
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ContactDetailsViewController_iPad' . 
I've never seen it before. My app is working fine with ios9 . Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to give more to go on that just the error message. Are you using storyboards? Are you loading them programmatically? If so post code

Comment: did you checked Target Membership for your nib file

Comment: No , I only use xib file to create UI interface. I'm not using storyboards for my project. Thanks.

Comment: @AnshaD : Yes, I did.

Comment: did u works with xcode8 Beta?

Comment: I 'm working with xcode8 GM seed

Comment: try to remove the xib reference and add the file again then clean and rebuild u r project

Comment: Unfortunately , it is still crashed :(